# Discord bot is thinking that im in VC even if I'm not

Tags: discord.js, bots

I'm doing a bot that can play things in a voice channel, but the problem is the code thinks im in voice channel but I'm not. I use this code to check it

```
const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
if (!voice_channel) {return sendMessage('**Error**', '#FF0000', 'You need to be in voice 
channel to use this command.', message, Discord);}
```

I don't get any errors. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using

Comment: @Cannicide That's not correct. `message.member.voice.channel` is the voice channel that the member that sent the message is in. If it is defined **you are** in a voice channel assuming you are the one that sent the message.

Comment: Apologies, I confused myself for a second there @GentleAutumnRain. You are correct. The assumption of who sent the message is therefore at the core of this question.

Comment: @MrMythical I'm using latest version

Comment: @GentleAutumnRain Yeah makes sense but how do I get the actual voice channel to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a stab in the dark here due to the lack of information provided in the question, but a common problem could very well be the cause of this issue.

Make sure you have the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent added to your client. Without that, it will not be able to detect updates to voice chats and therefore, if you run your code while not a voice channel it will always think you're not in one and if you are in a voice channel when you run your code it will always think you are in one.

By just adding that  intent it will be able to detect updates and could/should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to `console.log(voice_channel)` and check if anything is different when you're connected and when you're not, and check if that value equals the value you got when you were not connected. I used to know this but I stopped making discord bots so I basically forgot everything I learned ;(

Comment: It looks like when I do this and im not in VC it says null but when I join VC it still says null.
Also I tried the code on another PC looks like it is discordjs problem not the code one.